# I get a segmentation fault (core dumped) error but only when half my code runs

Tags: c++

The goal of this code is to manipulate an ASCII "image" that comes in the form of a really long string that I print out on different lines

```
.............  
.............  
.XXX.....X...  
.XXX.....X...  
.XXX.........  
.XXX.........  
.XXXXXXX.....  
.XXXXXXX.....  
.XXXXXXX.....  
...........
```

It looks like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::fstream img(argv[1]);
    std::vector<char> path;
    char x;
    while (img >> x) {
        path.push_back(x);
    }
    for (char i = 0; i < path.size(); ++i) {
        if (i%13==0) {
            std::cout << path[i] << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << path[i];
        }
    }
    std::string replace = "replace";
    std::string dilation1 = "dilation";
    std::string erosion1 = "erosion";
    std::string floodfill1 = "floodfill";
    char old_char = argv[4][0];
    char new_char = argv[5][0];
    if (argv[3] == replace) {
        for (char n=0; n<path.size(); ++n) {
            if(path[n]==old_char) {
                path[n]=new_char;
            }
        }

        for (char i = 0; i < path.size(); ++i) {
            if (i%13==0) {
                std::cout << path[i] << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << path[i];
            }
        }
    }
    if (argv[3] == dilation1) {
        std::cout << "this is ok" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here is my code.
The replace part of the code is meant to take this as the input from the console

```
./image_processing.out input4.txt output4_replace.txt replace X O
```

and replace the X's with O's,
and it works.
But then, I move onto the dilation function which takes this as input from the console.

```
./image_processing.out input4.txt output4_dilation.txt dilation X
```

Nevermind what it does. Yet, I haven't even gotten that far because whenever I try to run the code with the second "if" statement, I get this

```
.............  
.............  
.XXX.....X...  
.XXX.....X...  
.XXX.........  
.XXX.........  
.XXXXXXX.....  
.XXXXXXX.....  
.XXXXXXX.....
```

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I don't know why it does this and I don't know why it only gets as far as the last line before it does that. When I comment out the second if statement, the code runs fine; however, it only does replace.

Comment: Well, have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: If your question is "how do you debug a core dump", you need to tell us about your platform and preferred debugger, and we don't need to see your code.

Comment: Does your ASCII "image" string have more than 127 characters in it?

Answer (score 0):

When running the program like this:

```
./image_processing.out input4.txt output4_dilation.txt dilation X
```

There are only 5 arguments, with valid indexes 0 - 4.  The line:

```
char new_char = argv[5][0];
```

is reading passed the end of argv array, as this assumes 6 arguments.